# Double value is changed on bind MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding

My problem is I have 3 double fields and when I try to bind these values it's changing the value typed in textbox.

Something like this:

```
Typed Value 5.4

Binded Value 54.0
```

Here goes my code:

**VIEW**

```
<div class="row jumbotron">
<div class="col-md-5">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                @Html.Hidden("customerId", new { customerId = ViewBag.customerId })
                @Html.Hidden("jobOffertId", new { jobOffertId = ViewBag.jobOffertId })

                <label>Descrição: </label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })

                <label>Confiança: </label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TrustPoints, new { @class = "form-control review" })

                <label>Qualidade do serviço: </label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.QualityPoints, new { @class = "form-control review" })

                <label>Pontualidade: </label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PunctualityPoints, new { @class = "form-control review" })

            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Criar avaliação" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**POST method**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateJobReview(JobReviewModel jobReviewModel, FormCollection data)
    {
        initBusinessObjects();

        Util.Common.ChangeContextInstance(null,null,null,jobOffertBusiness,jobReviewBusiness);

        var customerId = int.Parse(data["customerId"]);
        var jobOffertId = int.Parse(data["jobOffertId"]);

        var jobOffert = jobOffertBusiness.GetById(jobOffertId);

        jobReviewModel.JobOffert = jobOffert;

        jobReviewBusiness.Insert(jobReviewModel);

        return RedirectToAction("ViewAllJobOfferts", new { customerId = customerId });
    }
```

**EDIT**

I almost forget, if I just type: 5 it binds correctly (5.0)

Comment: Have you inspected the values being posted to ensure that they aren't being modified client side?

Comment: @tvanfosson The values are not being modified by client side.

Comment: Which are the double fields?

Comment: These: `model.TrustPoints, model.QualityPoints, model.PunctualityPoints`

Comment: I got this! The problem was the dot "." if I change this for a comma "," it works fine!

Comment: That is becouse of your culture in project. Some cultures has decimal separator dots and some comma...